# Grover search over k-ary strings

Tags: grovers-algorithm, resource-request

The textbook Grover search algorithm presented in many lecture notes ([eg.](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608150507023.pdf)) is over bitstrings $x \in \{0,1\}^{n}$. Typically the Grover operator is of the form $G = H U H V$ where $H$ is the Walsh-Hadamard transform for $n$-qubit states, and $U$ and $V$ are some reflections. Is it true with the substitution of $H$ for the Quantum Fourier Transform $\operatorname{QFT}_k$ over the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_k$ one can obtain an algorithm that solves the unstructured search problem over $k$-ary strings $x \in [k]^n$? Are there any difficulties that arise, or does this generalization just work? Could you provide some references that describe this more general setup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about the direction of the generalization. After a quick search I found these:

https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0932 - one of the earliest examples I found tracing back citations - maybe the first proposal?

The rest I found are around the same topic with different optimizations and implementation aspects - from which I gather that implementing/decomposing the q-ary Toffoli gate and in general finding a good gateset to implement the algorithm with are the key tricky bits in implementations.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4489

https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.04447

https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06316